# error in Doctype html while adding copied html folder

Tags: html, django, pycharm

{% load static %}

doctype HTML is showing an error-"Unwanted tokens". I have updated the directories, paths in settings, and in my HTML file whose content is from another Html file. As I have transferred important folders in the static folder.

Comment: instead of images you have to paste your code in text format

Comment: Please take a bit of time to read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and improve your question to increase the chances of getting good replies

Answer (score 0):

You have to run collectstatic first

`python manage.py collectstatic`

Please paste your code here and your error traceback

Answer (score 0):

```
{% load static %}
```

if u replace fisrt row it will solve the problem.

Comment: I did but the images and other features that were supposed to load are still not uploading after editing or removing the first row.I followed as per the instructions given in the lecture